# Number of elements in between two elements (Both Inclusive)

Tags: arrays, c

Given an unsorted array of size n, write a program to find number of elements between two user-defined elements a and b (where a and b both are inclusive) of a user-defined array.
Input : arr = [1, 2, 2, 7, 5, 4]
a=2 b=5
Output : 4

Here is my code. What is wrong with this code. Can you please explain me my mistake and explain the logic?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a[100],n,i,m,b,count=0;
    printf("Enter the number of elements you want to enter in any array:");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    printf("Enter the elements you want to enter in the array:\n");

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }
    
    printf("Array:\n");

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("%d\t",a[i]);
    }
    
   printf("\nEnter lower limit element & upper limit element respectively: ");
   scanf("%d %d",&m,&b);
    
   for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    { 
         if(a[i]==m || a[i]==b)
         {
            count++;
         }
        if(a[i]>m && a[i]<b)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }

    printf("Number of elements in between two elements (Both Inclusive) = %d",count);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You haven't actually described a specific error or incorrect behaviour in your program. Please give the exact input, expected result vs actual result. And have you made any attempt to debug your own code? Run it in a debugger to trace the program flow and variable values. That is one good way to find out where things first start going wrong.

Comment: for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    { 
         if(a[i]==m || a[i]==b)
         {
            count++;
         }
        if(a[i]>m && a[i]<b)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }

    printf("Number of elements in between two elements (Both Inclusive) = %d",count);
    return 0;                                                                                                                                                   The error is in this part of the program.

Comment: "*the error is in this part*". What error? Please be specific. And please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73129304/edit) the post y update it with such info, not in comments.

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre], including an exact copy of input that reproduces the problem, an exact copy of observed output, and an exact copy of the output desired instead. Define what “inclusive” means; does it mean to count from the first occurrence of the start number or the last occurrence of the start number and the first occurrence of the end number or the last occurrence of the end number?

Comment: `if(a[i]>m && a[i]<b)` This logic is wrong. Nothing in the task requirements state that `b` has to be greater than `m`. You need to find `m`, start counting and stop when you then find `b`. It's irrelevant what the numbers in between a and b are and you must not check the values like that as the numbers may not be between a and b in value (only in position).

Comment: Why is your program printing the contents of the array? Is that part of the problem specification?

Comment: @kaylum The logic is not wrong. There is clear written printf("\nEnter lower limit element & upper limit element respectively: ");

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: The prompt text in the program is not the assignment specification, and, even if it were, “lower” may refer to lower position in the array, not lower value of the element, and similarly for “upper.”

Comment: @EricPostpischil There is no any logical error in the program. The logic of the program is clear and straightforward. If there is no check whether for example the input was correct does not mean that there is a logical error. It means only that the program is unsafe and nothing more.

Comment: how is 4 the wrong answer? What are you expecting instead? For `m==2` and `b==5`, there are 4 elements in the array inclusively between those values: 2, 2, 4, and 5. Do you mean you want the number of _unique_ elements, and are expecting an output of 3?

Answer (score 1):

Think about the challenge. Rather than trying to count, simply find the index of each target and calculate the difference between them.

```
int loInd = -1, hiInd = -1;

for( i = 0; i < n; i++ ) { 
    if( a[ i ] == m && loInd < 0 )
        loInd = i;
    if( a[ i ] == b )
        hiInd = i;
}

if( loInd >= 0 && hiInd >= 0 )
    printf( "(Inclusive) Gap is %d\n", hiInd - loInd + 1 );
else
    printf( "value(s) not found\n" );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    { 
         if(a[i]==m || a[i]==b)
         {
            count++;
         }
        if(a[i]>m && a[i]<b)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
```

The logic of this part of code is to count the array element whose VALUE is between a and b. But i guess the subject is to count elements whose POSITION IN ARRAY between a and b.

For example a array = { 0, 2, 4, 1, 3, 5}, given a = 2, b = 3
When count value between a and b include a and b, the result should be 2,3;
while count position between them, that should be 2,4,1,3
See difference?

And there are a lot redundancy of your code, you can write as:

```
   for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    { 
        if(a[i] >= m && a[i] <= b)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

There is no error in the logic, but you'd better use `else if` to make the logic judgment only execute once. Or just judge the case where no count is needed.

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (a[i] < m || a[i] > b) {
        continue;
    }
    count++;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).